# ImportError: cannot import name learn

Tags: tensorflow

I followed below url for creating docker and install tensorflow on the VM.

http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/

Everything gone fine. But when I tried to run below code, I see the error message as below

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib import learn

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e8c8ddf46f14> in <module>()
  1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow.contrib import learn

ImportError: cannot import name learn
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score -2):

You should not import anything manually.

Once you have done `import tensorflow as tf`, you can use `tf.contrib.learn`.

Please follow the [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/index.html).